# How to access all four cameras and show in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayers?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-camera

I can access at most 2 cameras at a time. Is there any way for accessing all four cameras of iPhone 12 and show them in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s too expensive in terms of memory and processing power. At most two cameras can be captured and only on newer devices (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemulticamsession/3183002-ismulticamsupported).

Comment: But how this app can do this? https://apps.apple.com/us/app/doubletake-by-filmic-pro/id1478041592

Comment: Interesting. So they can also only record two cameras at the same time. As for the selection screen, they actually manage to present 3 camera feeds. The telephoto is actually fake (just a cropped version of the wide-angle feed), as you can check by covering the respective lenses with a finger. My guess is that you can actually use 3 cameras, but only when you set the settings to very low so that the load on the system is managable.

Comment: Yea, thats right. But in 3 back camera phone. They can access total 3 cameras at a time.

Comment: But not for recording, right? Have you tried setting up an `AVCaptureMultiCamSession` with 3 cameras and a very low quality preset? I'm guessing the system is based on load (see `systemPressureCost` of the session).

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried with a low quality preset. How to do that?

Comment: `session.sessionPreset = .low` before you add any inputs/outputs should work.

Comment: Crushed "AVCaptureSessionPresetLow is not a supported preset"

Comment: Ah, my bad! From the docs: "The session preset for a multicamera session is always `inputPriority`. Set each capture device’s `activeFormat` value to the desired quality of service." So you have to set the `activeFormat` of each device to some format with a low resolution (check the device's `formats` for available options).